# Observable Chaining in Angular 2's new HttpClient

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have a simple and common scenario and I can't get my head around the correct way to do this with the new `HttpClient`. I'm coming from Angular 1 and chainable `then()` promises and not sure how to achieve this with Observables. (Would be great if Tour of Heroes tutorial was updated to reflect the shift onto HttpClient).

I have a main `app.component.ts`. This component will call a `AuthenticationService.login()` in `authentication.service.ts`.

`AuthenticationService` serves two purposes:

1. It coordinates all client/server communication regarding authentication.
2. It stores authentication information that can be shared across any and/or all components.

The code is ideally very simple (note: this is just contrived pseudocode)

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  loggedIn: boolean = false;

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
  }

  login() {
    // I want to do this but don't know how
    this.authenticationService.login(this.userLoginForm.email, this.userLoginForm.password).then(function(loggedIn) {
      this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
    }
  }
}
```

authentication.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  user: User;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // do stuff
  }

  // Recommendations I'm reading tend to prefer using Observables
  // instead of Promises. But I like the `then()` chaining that
  // I'm not sure how to do with Observables

  // Return what here? Observable<boolean> ?
  login(email, password): Observable<boolean> {
      const url = `http://127.0.0.1/token/auth`;

      // post() returns a LoginResponse that we subscribe to and handle here,
      // but I want to return a promise-like object that will resolve to
      // a boolean
      return this.http.post<LoginResponse>(url, {email: email, password: password})
          .subscribe(
            loginResponse => {
              if (loginResponse.error) {
                // set user to a new unauthenticated user
                this.user = new User();
              } else {
                this.user = JSON.parse(loginResponse.data.user) as User;
              }

              localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.user));

              // returning a boolean here to the caller would be nice
              return this.user.id != null;
            }
          }
        );  
  );
```

}

What am I missing here? Isn't this trivial?

Arguably, there is no need to return a boolean here. `app.component.ts` can just read AuthenticationService.user to know if the user is logged in or not? Is that the way to do it?

More generally though, there surely must be a way for a service to process data returned from a server and then resolve promises that the calling component is waiting on. How does one do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Obervable.map to transform things into what your service should return (you want an observable of boolean here). Use observable everywhere so change .then into .subscribe in your component.

```
// Your service:

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

    user: User;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // do stuff
    }

    login(email, password): Observable<boolean> {

        const url = `http://127.0.0.1/token/auth`;

        return this.http.post<LoginResponse>(url, { email: email, password: password })
            .map(loginResponse => {
                this.user = loginResponse.error ? new User() : (JSON.parse(loginResponse.data.user) as User);
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.user));
                return this.user.id != null;
            }
    }        
}

// Your component
export class AppComponent {

    loggedIn: boolean = false;

    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    login() {
        this.authenticationService.login(this.userLoginForm.email, this.userLoginForm.password).subscribe(loggedIn =>  this.loggedIn = loggedIn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I guess the next question is, does it make sense to return an Observable at all, or should this just be converted to a Promise and returned? That may be an entirely different question that could be asked in a separate post.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `Observable` into the `Promise` using [**toPromise()**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md)  function. Now your `login` will return `Promise`, not an `Observable` and you can chain it via `then`s.

```
login(email, password) : Promise {
      const url = `http://127.0.0.1/token/auth`;

      return this.http.post<LoginResponse>(url, {email: email, password: password})
          .toPromise().then(loginResponse => {
              this.user = loginResponse.error ? this.user = new User() :
                                                JSON.parse(loginResponse.data.user) as User;

              localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.user));

              return this.user.id !== null;
          });  
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

Right, but I guess it seems that using Observables if usually preferred in Angular 2. I'm not sure though, as there seem to many use-cases where promises themselves make more sense. I like @Faly's answer using Observables with the map() function as it seems the most Angular 2-ish. We could just call map(do some stuff).toPromise() and also have the same effect.

In my case, not sure if returning an Observable or Promise is better. Seems like a Promise is better here. This is just a boolean, not a stream or anything fancy.

Comment: @lostdorje as you said that you want `then` solution, so I answered with that

Comment: Right, you did! I was familiar with .toPromise(). The .map()-> Observable -> .map() etc has the same more angular 2-ish effect. Thanks for the help!